# Files Arrangement

Tags: nautilus

Even after selecting arrange items by type in preference menu of the Files(Nautilus) on Debian 8.2 ,the items are not arranged by type.I have everything mixed up from .pdf's in between .mp4's to .zip.Any help is appreciated.[image]

Comment: I think you mean they are not arranged by extension...

Comment: May be you are right.Is there any diffrence b/w by type and by extension?

Comment: Yes. The file type is one of socket, fifo, character, block dev, dir, regular, symlink, and so on. The extension is what follows the . in a file name.

Comment: Thanks,then what's the criteria used by Gnome Files in arranging by file type?Is it the extension?

Comment: I would expect it to be the type, possibly expanded to recognize [MIME](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) or *content* types.

Comment: In short,Is it functioning perfectly ok or not in my case?

Comment: looks good to me.

Comment: Shouldn't the two .zip files be together?